# How do I use XHR to return an encoded URL to ng-src inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have images I need to pull from a server requiring basic authentication. To do that I couldn't just place the URL inside ng-src because I couldn't send an authenticated request, so I manually pull the image data using XHR.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", 'https://url.com/{id}/picture', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(userID + ":" + password));
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(evt) {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        var i = uInt8Array.length;
        var binaryString = new Array(i);
        while(i--) {
            binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
        }
        var data = binaryString.join('');
        var base64 = window.btoa(data);
        document.getElementById("test").src="data:"+xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')+";base64,"+base64;
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Replacing the URL in the code above with the actual path to a picture works and displays the picture inside a div called `test`.

Now I need to display a list of these images.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in array">
        <td">
            <div>
                <img data-ng-src={{getPictureURL()}} onerror="this.onError=null;this.src='default.png'" >
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Heart of the question:
I put in the first code block into `getPictureURL()`, replacing `document.getElementById("test").src=` with `return`, and it will send a massive number of requests because of ng-repeat and xhr.open opening a connection to the picture URL every iteration on each item in `array`. I know that `ng-src` won't reload a picture even in `ng-repeat` until there is a change in the path to the image. So ultimately, I want to get and return the base64-encoded URL in `getPictureURL()` so it can display the pictures.

What should I do?

Comment: A vague hint, use `$q.all` API, to call multiple XHR requests & use `.when` to set all paths at last.

Comment: You need to load these into data model first , don't use function in view. Also consider caching the requests

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613534/angular-http-how-to-call-images-with-custom-headers)